# Selectively restrict sync for some applications to wifi only

Tags: sync, samsung-galaxy-nexus, 4.1-jelly-bean

I know it's been asked here how to prevent applications from using data connections. But that is not my intent. I have a Galaxy Nexus running Jelly Bean 4.1.1 and I would like to restrict most of applications to use my data connection. But would allow some to use it.

For instance I would like to restrict Currents, Google+, Facebook, Maps and Google Now from using my data connection. But I would like GMail and Talk to use it.

How can I do this? And is it also possible to set sync frequency when wither on Wifi or Data connection?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go into `Settings | Data usage`. Then in the `Mobile` tab, you'll find a list of the applications that have recently used data.

Click on any of these applications and there will be a checkbox to **restrict background data** while the phone is using a mobile connection (as opposed to wifi).

I'm not aware of a way to control the sync frequency.

Comment: Thanks. I've seen that but was hesitant to check those checkboxes because it says that some apps may fail... I guess that's just a warning then that should be ignored most of the time then?

Comment: I've only seen one application "fail" with an error like "cannot download new content". As far as I'm concerned, that's exactly what I want while I'm not on wifi :)

Answer (score 0):

Im also looking for a similar app.
I will try [Root Firewall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rootuninstaller.firewall).

Comment: BTW: *Restrict background data* works pretty well in my expereince. Some apps may still do some very very minor traffic but I find it negligible.

Answer (score 0):

To sync frequency go to Settings -  under Applications - email - manage accounts - tap on the account you want to sync - sync settings - sync schedule - set sync schedule.  This works on my Galaxy S5

Comment: This must be Samsung's customization because I can't seem to find settings you're referring to.

Answer (score 0):

NetGuard is an app that does what you're looking for. It allows you to selectively block everything/anything from data/wifi. It's also 100% free and open-source, so you don't have to worry about ads/malware. 

The [F-Droid version](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=eu.faircode.netguard) has significantly more features than the less-powerful [Google Play variant.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.faircode.netguard&hl=en)